# notepad++ "autotext"-type plugin

Tags: automation, plugins, notepad++, typing

As part of my job, I regularly enter long descriptions of real estate into a database. I type those up in N++ and then paste them into the web interface of the base. However, they are quite repetitive, and I would like to make my life easier.

I was thinking of something like this. For example, I would type `opl`, and as soon as I hit space, it would be replaced with `open plan living room with kitchen`. So is there a plugin for Notepad++ to do this? I know that it has autocompletion, but that works a bit differently from what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check out the [Auto-Completion features](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/editing/auto-completion) built into Notepad++ 5 and above.

> Notepad++ has autocompletion capabilities, allowing it to finish a word that you are typing by giving a list of possible options, or immediately inserting it when only one possibility is left (powered by the Scintilla component).
>
> There are two types of auto completion:
>
> The first one uses a list of well known keywords and provides a hint based on that and goes by the name Function Completion. It is triggered by selecting Edit->Auto-Completion->Function Completion or automatically when a certain amount of characters is typed (see also Preferences).
>
> The second one retrieves all the words from the current file and provides hinting on that, named Word Completion. This is triggered by selecting Edit->Auto-Completion->Word Completion, or by entering a set number of characters (again, see Preferences). Word completion is the only type that can automatically finish a word without displaying a list of options first.

Answer (score 1):

If you can/are willing to install another program, try AutoHotkey (http://www.autohotkey.com/), which can do the keyword substitution you describe and more, not only in Notepad++ but most other applications.